# if statement of many things ruby

Tags: ruby

Simply question but trying to see if there is an easier way:

```
if @integration.provider == "hello" || @integration.provider == "hi"
  #block of code
end
```

Is there an easier way to just have `"hello" || "hi"` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Enumerable#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) will determine if a value is found in a given array.

```
if ["hello", "hi"].include? @integration.provider
```

Alternative syntax for strings:

```
if %w(hello hi).include? @integration.provider
```

Comment: what happens if you want to do an and, `&&`

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy Can you give an example? `@integration.provider` can't be two different values.